# What's the deal with mime types in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types

I'm confused by the number of different modules that deal with mime types in Rails.  There are three that I have in mind, if somebody could straighten this out for me I would be grateful.

1) Mime::Type (for respond_to)

```
Mime::Type.register "text/richtext", :rtf
```

2) MIME::Types (from the mime-types gem)

```
MIME::Types[/ogg/, :complete => true]
```

3) Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES (for serving content)

```
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.merge!({".ogg" => "audio/ogg"})
```

Are these three completely separate or is there any connection between them?  It seems strange to maintain 3 different lists of mime types, but their purposes do seem disjoint, I guess.

More specifically, how should I know which of these to register a new type with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some waffle of an answer...

Rails (1) and Rack (3) were separate, so I guess that explains the split there - and hopefully at some point Rails will use the Rack one now that its Rack-based...

As for (2), this seems to be a non-Rails/Rack library for identifying a files type - http://mime-types.rubyforge.org/ - so perhaps the ideal future would be for Rails and Rack to be based on this... although it seems quite old now (2009) and is perhaps un-maintained, hence the lack of use...